# Hibernate 5.0.1 Final Problems;

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

So, Im working in a project, and my task is to update the current hibernate version 3.x to the latest. I did it, fixing all the incompatibility errors. But when Im trying to start Tomcat, I am getting an exception saying

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/type/BasicType`.

I've goggled my problem and wasted all the day to fix it, but didn´t found nothing usefull. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/type/BasicType
```

indicates that the JVM is looking for the `class BasicType` in your classpath and it cannot find it as the package `org.hibernate.type` is not included in your classpath.

Simply put, add the package to your classpath.

Comment: Thanks, but, doing that, I have the same issue. :/ I have tryied adding the hibernate-core jar files to the classpath, but, that doesnt help me.

Comment: Roman How are you adding the jars to classpath ?Through some IDE like eclipse ?

Comment: Yes, through eclipse IDE. In Java Build Path.

Comment: Well, I could solve that issue, but now Im getting a new one saying `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file`. Now will look for solution. Thanks